# how to click a link using page object in watir-webdriver with cucumber

Tags: watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

I want to use page objects for my project and need to know how to click on link as I have tried with methods which I got from the google search but it is not working. step definition is

```
Given /^I navigate to the RCM Home Page$/ do
 visit_page HomePage
end

When /^I click the Show Filters Link$/ do
 @current_page.show_filters
end
```

my page object class file is

```
class HomePage
 include PageObject
 page_url Common.get_url('rcm')
 link(:show_filters, :id       => "portletComponentWorkList_viewNormalModeWorkList_viewPanel_showFiltersLink")
end
```

my .feature file is

```
Feature: RCM Workspace basic features test

 Scenario: Perform basic operations on RCM project
  Given I navigate to the RCM Home Page
  When I click the Show Filters Link
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "not working"?

Comment: I have executed the scenario and I am expecting that it should click 'Show filters' link which is displayed on home page. But it is showing error message as        Given I navigate to the RCM Home Page           # features/step_definitions/homepage_steps.rb:1
    When I click the Show Filters Link              # features/step_definitions/homepage_steps.rb:5
      The xpath expression './/a[@id='portletComponentWorkList_viewNormalModeWorkList_viewPanel_showFiltersLink']' cannot be evaluated or does notresult in a We
bElement (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidSelectorError)
      (eval):1:in

Comment: Is the link in a frame? I think that was the problem in your previous questions?

Comment: Sounds like your xpath expression is bogus, or else the element can't be found.  Share some of the HTML and perhaps we can suggest how to more easily identify the object without resorting to xpath.  Also there are a number of page object libraries around, so knowing which specific one you are using is helpful.  (for example I use Test-Factory because it is fairly light weight and well optimized for watir)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
@current_page.show_filters.click
```

Comment: Can you explain me which pageobject gem is fine and do I need to know all the methods again or is it similar to Watir methods.

Comment: @ravichandra naidu you can get all the information from the following link
https://github.com/cheezy/page-object

Comment: Hi it is throwing error, so I mentioned same thing in my question. Any answers please.

Comment: @ravichandranaidu can you please let us know the steps that you followed & the error that you encountered, as its really hard to help you without a  proper description of your issue.